# NodeJS - How to persist a raw object to reuse it later

Tags: node.js, file, persistence

I would like to save a raw array of objects in a file after my script stops to reuse when I restart it (I aggregate a lot of data and I don't want to do it all the time). The issue is that each object is gigantic AND the parameters can change (type) so it seems like a solution like node-persist doesn't do it for me e.g.

```
fs.write(myArray, "/data.raw")
```

In addition, I would like to be able to reuse it with a file read when I restart my script e.g.

```
myArray = fs.read("/data.raw")
```

Do you know a lib doing this and abstracting fs basically? (cause otherwise the types conversions with text might be cumbersome)

Or do I have to use JSON.Stringify()?

Or should I use a DB? (but imho it would be the same as I wont be able to store key/value so it would end up as a Blob)

thanks for your help!

Comment: Well, `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` are the usual simplest choices as long as you don't have any circular references or custom classes within your structure.  Other than that, you have to write your own converters from Javascript to some format you can persist to disk (text or binary).  CSV is a common one, but you can also make your own custom format that can sometimes be more efficient than either JSON or CSV.  It really depends upon the specifics of your data and how important efficiency is.  First thing to consider is JSON with `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Using a database is a whole different direction.  It wouldn't really make sense to store it as a single blob (anything you can store as a blob in a database can be just written to a file), it would make more sense to store the array in the database where each entry in the array was a record in your database and then just use the data from the database instead of bringing it all into an in-memory Javascript array.

Comment: thanks @jfriend00, indeed this is where I was going ;) stringify + file